# deletion of folders

Tags: python, directory

how can i delete a folder using python script?and what are the return values??

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete a folder that's empty use [os.rmdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rmdir):

```
import os
os.rmdir('/mypath')
```

If you want to delete a folder that's not empty use [shutil.rmtree](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree):

```
import shutil  
shutil.rmtree('/mypath')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `os.rmdir()` to remove a directory. To remove a directory tree recursively, you can use `shutil.rmtree`. If you know that you already have empty directory nodes, you can also check out `os.removedirs()`